# Building Julia 1.9.2 from source on WSL2 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: build, julia, wsl-2

Following the *Building Julia* section from the current *julia* Github readme on the master branch, I'm trying to build Julia 1.9.2 from source on WSL 2 Ubuntu.
I've installed all dependencies and have no spaces or other shell meta-characters in the filesystem.

The `make` (with no argument) seems to work and I'm able to run the executable, but the `make testall` fails with the following summary:

```
Test Summary:                                     |     Pass  Error  Broken     Total      Time
  Overall                                         | 28473073      4   25056  28498133  28m07.3s
    LinearAlgebra/structuredbroadcast             |      670                      670   1m26.6s
    LinearAlgebra/blas                            |     1630                     1630   2m17.8s
    LinearAlgebra/hessenberg                      |      632                      632   2m35.6s
    LinearAlgebra/svd                             |      606                      606   2m48.0s
    LinearAlgebra/uniformscaling                  |      446                      446   2m50.8s
    LinearAlgebra/qr                              |     4705                     4705   3m44.6s
    LinearAlgebra/adjtrans                        |      475                      475   1m00.8s
    LinearAlgebra/lapack                          |      803                      803   1m17.7s
    LinearAlgebra/tridiag                         |     1601                     1601   1m50.9s
    LinearAlgebra/lu                              |     1380                     1380   4m28.3s
    LinearAlgebra/givens                          |     1991                     1991     21.7s
    LinearAlgebra/cholesky                        |     2511                     2511   4m31.2s
    LinearAlgebra/ldlt                            |        8                        8      1.9s
    LinearAlgebra/factorization                   |       80             16        96      7.6s
    LinearAlgebra/eigen                           |      951                      951   3m11.6s
    ambiguous                                     |      108              2       110      8.6s
    compiler/datastructures                       |      294                      294      5.0s
    compiler/validation                           |       28                       28      0.9s
    compiler/effects                              |      556              1       557      3.7s
    LinearAlgebra/lq                              |     3098                     3098   1m59.8s
    LinearAlgebra/pinv                            |      500                      500     21.8s
    compiler/irpasses                             |      249              4       253      9.9s
    compiler/contextual                           |       12                       12      4.8s
    compiler/ssair                                |      135                      135     17.4s
    compiler/inline                               |      268              3       271     13.5s
    LinearAlgebra/schur                           |      496                      496   1m13.6s
    compiler/inference                            |     1263              4      1267     28.4s
    LinearAlgebra/generic                         |      644              1       645   1m22.3s
    compiler/codegen                              |      183                      183     19.2s
    strings/search                                |      876                      876     10.6s
    strings/io                                    |    12764                    12764      6.6s
    strings/basic                                 |    87696                    87696     17.5s
    unicode/utf8                                  |       19                       19      0.2s
    compiler/EscapeAnalysis/interprocedural       |       32              4        36     22.9s
    strings/types                                 |  2302691                  2302691      5.9s
    strings/util                                  |     1152                     1152     25.8s
    compiler/EscapeAnalysis/local                 |      347             21       368     32.7s
    keywordargs                                   |      154                      154      3.9s
    LinearAlgebra/bunchkaufman                    |     5689                     5689   1m44.3s
    worlds                                        |      103                      103     12.6s
    triplequote                                   |       29                       29      0.1s
    char                                          |     1639                     1639      4.7s
    intrinsics                                    |      364                      364      7.2s
    compiler/AbstractInterpreter                  |       24                       24     50.3s
    iobuffer                                      |      209                      209      3.1s
    staged                                        |       67                       67      6.2s
    atomics                                       |     3448                     3448     39.1s
    subtype                                       |   337952             42    337994     43.2s
    hashing                                       |    14436                    14436     39.1s
    dict                                          |   144450                   144450     58.8s
    tuple                                         |      670                      670     22.0s
    reduce                                        |     8598                     8598     44.3s
    intfuncs                                      |   227917                   227917     20.1s
    offsetarray                                   |      513              3       516   1m32.9s
    simdloop                                      |      240                      240      4.0s
    vecelement                                    |      678                      678     14.9s
    LinearAlgebra/special                         |     3008                     3008   7m49.7s
    copy                                          |      556                      556      7.8s
    LinearAlgebra/bidiag                          |     4792                     4792   8m07.1s
    numbers                                       |  1584929              1   1584930   2m44.7s
    fastmath                                      |      946                      946     17.9s
    core                                          |  8445963              3   8445966   3m01.8s
    functional                                    |       98                       98     14.7s
    rational                                      |    98695              2     98697   1m01.9s
    path                                          |      373             12       385      3.0s
    operators                                     |    13055                    13055     19.8s
    ordering                                      |       37                       37     13.7s
    parse                                         |    16098                    16098      8.8s
    gmp                                           |     2445                     2445     11.9s
    reducedim                                     |     1225              6      1231   2m55.6s
    spawn                                         |      242              4       246     35.2s
    math                                          |  1909858                  1909858   2m15.2s
    backtrace                                     |       39              1        40      3.4s
    exceptions                                    |       70                       70      2.8s
    arrayops                                      |     2122              5      2127   4m06.5s
    version                                       |     2453                     2453      2.3s
    namedtuple                                    |      218                      218      6.2s
    file                                          |     1072                     1072     16.5s
    LinearAlgebra/dense                           |     8561                     8561  10m45.7s
    LinearAlgebra/diagonal                        |               1                 1  10m58.7s
    loading                                       |   140378                   140378   2m12.8s
    floatapprox                                   |       49                       49      4.2s
    read                                          |     3812                     3812     52.9s
    mpfr                                          |     1137              1      1138     45.8s
    regex                                         |      142                      142      6.7s
    sysinfo                                       |        4                        4      0.4s
    env                                           |       76                       76      1.1s
    complex                                       |     8480              2      8482     30.6s
    reflection                                    |      434                      434     12.7s
    mod2pi                                        |       80                       80      0.6s
    float16                                       |   762093                   762093     11.4s
    euler                                         |       12                       12      2.6s
    combinatorics                                 |      170                      170     14.6s
    client                                        |        5                        5      4.3s
    rounding                                      |   150016                   150016     11.6s
    goto                                          |       19                       19      0.3s
    llvmcall                                      |       20                       20      1.6s
    llvmcall2                                     |       20                       20      0.3s
    ryu                                           |    31217                    31217      2.8s
    some                                          |       72                       72      1.8s
    abstractarray                                 |    55663          24806     80469   4m51.9s
    meta                                          |       69                       69      3.4s
    stacktraces                                   |       48                       48     13.7s
    docs                                          |      239                      239     10.6s
    errorshow                                     |      249                      249     24.6s
    iterators                                     |    86616                    86616   3m29.0s
    binaryplatforms                               |      341                      341     11.2s
    enums                                         |      102                      102      9.2s
    atexit                                        |       68                       68     26.1s
    interpreter                                   |        3                        3      1.5s
    ccall                                         |     5400                     5400   3m40.5s
    int                                           |   736188                   736188     22.7s
    bitset                                        |      200                      200      9.9s
    sets                                          |     3644              1      3645   1m11.4s
    error                                         |       83                       83      6.2s
    ranges                                        |               1                 1   1m32.2s
    show                                          |   128982              8    128990   1m28.7s
    checked                                       |     1239                     1239     33.7s
    osutils                                       |     1000                     1000      2.1s
    boundscheck                                   |                              None     21.8s
    iostream                                      |       50                       50      3.2s
    specificity                                   |      175                      175      0.3s
    secretbuffer                                  |       30                       30      4.1s
    cartesian                                     |      349              3       352     18.1s
    corelogging                                   |      235                      235     10.6s
    broadcast                                     |      526                      526   2m36.1s
    smallarrayshrink                              |       36                       36      1.8s
    opaque_closure                                |       68              1        69      3.1s
    filesystem                                    |        6                        6      0.8s
    syntax                                        |     1679              1      1680     19.7s
    SparseArrays/allowscalar                      |        9                        9      0.8s
    misc                                          |  1282251                  1282251   1m31.1s
    SparseArrays/ambiguous                        |        1                        1      6.7s
    asyncmap                                      |      307                      307     21.0s
    bitarray                                      |   940200              8    940208   5m43.9s
    channels                                      |      259                      259     44.9s
    LinearAlgebra/symmetric                       |     2853                     2853  13m35.4s
    SparseArrays/fixed                            |       58                       58     16.4s
    reinterpretarray                              |      421                      421     46.3s
    download                                      |                              None     31.8s
    missing                                       |      574              1       575     54.2s
    LinearAlgebra/matmul                          |     1496                     1496  14m09.2s
    subarray                                      |   459022                   459022   9m24.1s
    sorting                                       |               1                 1   5m30.9s
    LibGit2/online                                |       10                       10      9.4s
    SparseArrays/spqr                             |       98                       98     44.4s
    Dates/accessors                               |  7723858                  7723858     11.8s
    Dates/query                                   |     1004                     1004      2.4s
    Dates/adjusters                               |     3149                     3149     14.0s
    SparseArrays/linalg_solvers                   |      364                      364   1m26.8s
    Dates/rounding                                |      315                      315      6.6s
    Dates/types                                   |      232                      232      4.2s
    SparseArrays/cholmod                          |      612                      612   1m56.4s
    Dates/periods                                 |      953                      953     34.9s
    Dates/arithmetic                              |      385                      385     14.9s
    Dates/conversions                             |      160                      160      2.1s
    Dates/ranges                                  |   350639                   350639     34.9s
    Base64                                        |     2031                     2031      4.8s
    Artifacts                                     |     1453                     1453      7.7s
    CompilerSupportLibraries_jll                  |        4                        4      1.3s
    CRC32c                                        |      664                      664      1.8s
    Dates/io                                      |      361                      361     30.9s
    ArgTools                                      |      180                      180     14.3s
    Future                                        |                              None      0.0s
    GMP_jll                                       |        1                        1      2.2s
    DelimitedFiles                                |       89                       89     12.5s
    LLD_jll                                       |        2                        2      0.9s
    LLVMLibUnwind_jll                             |                              None      0.8s
    LibGit2/libgit2                               |               1                 1   1m20.5s
    LazyArtifacts                                 |        4                        4      7.7s
    LibCURL                                       |        6                        6      2.0s
    LibCURL_jll                                   |        1                        1      0.1s
    SparseArrays/sparsematrix_ops                 |      675                      675   2m24.8s
    LibSSH2_jll                                   |                              None      1.5s
    LibGit2_jll                                   |        2                        2      3.2s
    LibUV_jll                                     |        1                        1      0.9s
    LibUnwind_jll                                 |        1                        1      0.8s
    MPFR_jll                                      |        1                        1      0.7s
    SparseArrays/umfpack                          |      345                      345   2m01.3s
    MbedTLS_jll                                   |        1                        1      0.4s
    Logging                                       |       40                       40      2.9s
    MozillaCACerts_jll                            |        1                        1      0.0s
    Libdl                                         |       79              1        80      4.1s
    OpenBLAS_jll                                  |        1                        1      0.1s
    OpenLibm_jll                                  |        1                        1      1.0s
    NetworkOptions                                |     3518                     3518      2.4s
    PCRE2_jll                                     |        7                        7      0.8s
    SparseArrays/issues                           |      349                      349   2m42.9s
    Markdown                                      |      257                      257     11.7s
    floatfuncs                                    |      232                      232   3m59.8s
    InteractiveUtils                              |      301                      301     42.3s
    Printf                                        |     1017                     1017     28.4s
    Mmap                                          |      140                      140     35.1s
    Serialization                                 |      131              1       132     14.5s
    SparseArrays/linalg                           |     4631                     4631   3m28.8s
    SuiteSparse                                   |                              None      1.3s
    SuiteSparse_jll                               |        1                        1      0.8s
    Sockets                                       |      173                      173     29.9s
    REPL                                          |     1583              3      1586   1m03.2s
    Downloads                                     |      238                      238   1m52.2s
    UUIDs                                         |     1029                     1029      0.7s
    TOML                                          |      582             45       627     33.7s
    Zlib_jll                                      |        1                        1      0.8s
    dSFMT_jll                                     |        1                        1      0.7s
    libLLVM_jll                                   |        1                        1      0.7s
    libblastrampoline_jll                         |        1                        1      0.0s
    nghttp2_jll                                   |        1                        1      0.1s
    p7zip_jll                                     |        1                        1      0.0s
    Unicode                                       |      795                      795      9.5s
    SparseArrays/higherorderfns                   |     7172              1      7173   4m17.3s
    Tar                                           |     3227             11      3238     46.0s
    SHA                                           |      107                      107   1m38.7s
    FileWatching                                  |      681                      681   2m25.3s
    cmdlineargs                                   |      275              5       280   6m16.0s
    Random                                        |   204840                   204840   2m03.7s
    Test                                          |      458             17       475   1m06.1s
    Statistics                                    |      810                      810   1m56.5s
    SparseArrays/sparsematrix_constructors_indexing |     1915                     1915   5m16.6s
    LinearAlgebra/triangular                      |    37908                    37908  20m06.8s
    Profile                                       |      116                      116   3m56.6s
    SparseArrays/sparsevector                     |    10509              4     10513   6m29.4s
    LinearAlgebra/addmul                          |    13644                    13644  24m00.1s
    Pkg                                           |     3258              1      3259  11m53.0s
    precompile                                    |      228                      228     41.6s
    SharedArrays                                  |      118                      118     23.0s
    threads                                       |       51                       51   1m47.3s
    Distributed                                   |       15                       15   3m17.8s
    stress                                        |      118                      118     11.3s
    FAILURE
```

I’m getting a lot of exceptions related to the file: *stdlib/v1.9/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl*.
I also get some *TCPSocket* related issues.

How do I fix this ? Should I consider my installation to be broken ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but why do you want to build from source? Just installing `juliaup` and using that to manage your Julia installations is quite convenient on Linux.

Comment: I'm building from source to get practice. Thanks for the tip though :)